# How do I approach proving a space is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

How do I determine whether or not this is a subspace of $\Bbb{F}^3$?

$\{ (x_1, x_2, x_3)\in\Bbb{F}^3: x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 = 0 \}$

If I wanted to *disprove* this being a subspace, I would just need to find a case where some vector violates closure or that it doesn't have a 0 vector. But how would I prove that it doesn't violate closure for multiplication or addition for all values within its space? What approach should I take for this and other polynomials that have some kind of condition?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Note that when we deal with linear homogeneous conditions on the components expressed by equalities (almost?) always we are dealing with a subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disprove that it is a subspace it suffices to find an element in the set which violates *at least one* of the required properties that is

$1) \ \vec{0} \in W$

$2) \ \vec{v}+\vec{w} \in W$

$3) \ \vec{cv}\to c \cdot \vec{v} \ ,c \in \mathbb{F}$

Otherwise to check whether the set is a subspace we need to check that all the properties hold for any vector in the set.

For example, clearly property "$1)$" is satisfied indeed

$$(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(0,0,0)\implies 0+2\cdot 0+3\cdot 0=0$$

For property "$2)$" let consider $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ in the set then note that

$$x_1+2x_2+3x_3+y_1+2y_2+3y_3=(x_1+y_1)+2(x_2+y_2)+3(x_3+y_3)=0$$

then also the sum is in the set.

For property "$3)$" let consider $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in the set then $\forall c$

$$x_1+2x_2+3x_3=0 \implies cx_1+2cx_2+3cx_3=0$$

then also any multiple is in the set.

We can't find any cunterexample in that case.

Comment: Thanks this was pretty clear. For your proof in property 2 and 3, what axiom or theorem are you using to say that the numbers will still equal to zero because the coefficients will be the same?

Comment: @Jaigus For 2), since the 2 vectors are in the ser we have $$(x_1+2x_2+3x_3)=0 \quad (y_1+2y_2+3y_3)=0\implies (x_1+2x_2+3x_3)+(y_1+2y_2+3y_3)=0$$ and so for the 3).